# How do I find the final "link in the chain" using a recursive CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm close on this but missing something.  How do I only get the first and last links in chains such as A->B, B->C? How do I just get A->C?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chains (
    cname TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    becomes TEXT
);

INSERT INTO chains
VALUES
    ('A', NULL),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('C', 'D'),
    ('D', 'E'),
    ('E', NULL)
;

WITH RECURSIVE
final_link AS (
SELECT
    chains.cname,
    chains.becomes
FROM
    chains

UNION

SELECT
    chains.cname,
    final_link.becomes
FROM
    chains
    INNER JOIN final_link
    ON chains.becomes = final_link.cname
)
SELECT * FROM final_link;
```

The results I would like are:

```
cname | becomes
------|--------
'B'   | 'E'
'C'   | 'E'
'D'   | 'E'
```

Comment: In your example `chains`, the first link is `B->C` and the last one is `D->E`, not `A->B` and `B->C`?

Comment: @Bergi. Maybe I stated it poorly.  I want B->E.  I don't want any intermediate steps. And then I want C->E without any intermediate steps.

Comment: Ah, the whole chain, not a specific link, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by starting the recursion only with the chain ends, not with all links, then iteratively prepending links as you are already doing:

```
WITH RECURSIVE final_link AS (
  SELECT cname, becomes
  FROM chains c
  WHERE (SELECT becomes IS NULL FROM chains WHERE cname = c.becomes)
UNION
  SELECT c.cname, fl.becomes
  FROM chains c
  INNER JOIN final_link fl ON c.becomes = fl.cname
)
SELECT * FROM final_link;
```

([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b577ee1b92cedfe28f8a11f2f2c3bc47))

Comment: Ha.  That's what I was trying to do.  I tried a couple of different where clauses but wasn't quite getting it right.  What exactly do you mean by "prepending" in this instance?  I think I'm missing some piece of understanding of how the recursive CTEs work, mechanically.

Comment: @GregoryArenius "prepending" refers to your chain of links here. Recursice CTEs are evaluated by starting with the non-recursive part (base case) and then iteratively adding to the set until it doesn't grow any longer. [These](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=564f0667f4f9daa4bce7ad116e3b7cfe) would be the steps

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach:

```
with recursive final_link as (
    select cname, becomes, cname original_cname, 0 lvl 
    from chains 
    where becomes is not null
    union all
    select c.cname, c.becomes , f.original_cname, f.lvl + 1
    from chains c
    inner join final_link f on f.becomes = c.cname
    where c.becomes is not null
)
select distinct on (original_cname) original_cname, becomes 
from final_link 
order by original_cname, lvl desc
```

The idea is to have the subquery keep track of the starting node, and of the level of each node in the tree. You can then filter with `distinct on` in the outer query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=67d934ed5f0898f899579a7f6f00a500)**:

```
original_cname | becomes
:------------- | :------
B              | E      
C              | E      
D              | E
```

Comment: I don't think the level is even necessary.